# Modify CSS content editor yui

Tags: javascript, editor, yui

I've created a toggle button to display or not divs border. How can i modify the CSS of the content editor ?

Any idea ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skin your editor you'd better to visit [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/skinning_editor.html)

Comment: No i want to skin the content.